# Cleaning up contourplot() in R lattice by reducing font size in numerical notations

Tags: r, plot, contour, lattice

How to change the size of the labels in `contourplot {lattice}` to avoid the overlapping of numerical legends in [this simulation](https://www.r-bloggers.com/maximum-likelihood/):

[image]

? I tried without success things like `labcex` within the function, or inserting a `par(cex=.5)` before plotting.

Here is the code as in the linked tutorial:

```
diams = c(150, 124, 100, 107, 170, 144,
          113, 108, 92, 129, 123, 118)

# Obtain typical mean and standard deviation
mean(diams)

[1] 123.1667

sd(diams)
[1] 22.38438

# A simple function to calculate likelihood.
# Values quickly become very small
like = function(data, mu, sigma) {
  like = 1
  for(obs in data){
    like = like * 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma) *
                     exp(-1/2 * (obs - mu)^2/(sigma^2))
  }
  return(like)
}

# For example, likelihood of data if mu=120 and sigma=20
like(diams, 120, 20)
[1] 3.476384e-24

# A simple function to calculate log-likelihood.
# Values will be easier to manage
loglike = function(data, mu, sigma) {
  loglike = 0
    for(obs in data){
      loglike = loglike +
                log(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma) *
                       exp(-1/2 * (obs - mu)^2/(sigma^2)))
    }
    return(loglike)
}

# Example, log-likelihood of data if mu=120 and sigma=20
loglike(diams, 122, 20)
[1] -53.88605

# Let's try some combinations of parameters and
# plot the results
params = expand.grid(mu = seq(50, 200, 1),
                     sigma = seq(10, 40, 1))
params$logL = with(params, loglike(diams, mu, sigma))
summary(params)

library(lattice)
contourplot(logL ~ mu*sigma, data = params, cuts = 20)
```

Comment: See the `labels` argument in `?lattice::panel.levelplot`.  You could try passing something like `labels = list(cex = 0.5)` to `contourplot`.

Comment: @sboysel Thank you. This works.